# Android - What is best way of handling http call in OnCreate which doesn't get called on screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am learning android. Get stuck with a basic scenario of loading the data in oncreate of an activity. So I am trying to load the data as soon as i open my activity but when i change the screen orientation it gets called again. I understand that android restore the state of activity during screen orientation. so oncreate method get called. But my problem is once the data get downloaded i dont want to make an Http call over and over. What should be best possible way to handle this? I want different layout for different screen orientation but data is same. I have to load the data in oncreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retain your data across configuration changes, such as via a [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/viewmodel). Your `ViewModel` would be responsible for performing the Web request (directly or via a [repository](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)) and delivering the results to the activity, such as via [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/livedata).

Comment: I did try view model but its same issue it's making call everytime when I change orientation

Comment: Can you please provide a samle code / example. I may be implemented it wrong I guess

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui: "I did try view model but its same issue it's making call everytime when I change orientation " -- you might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing what you tried.

Comment: please have a look on new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586059/android-how-to-use-viewmodel-for-handling-http-call-in-oncreate-which-doesnt. I have posted code as well

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to CommonsWare answer if you don't want to use Google arch components you can simply check if `savedInstanceState` bundle is `null`. If it is then this if the first launch of activity and you can load your data. If it is not then it was re-created and you should not load the data.