# Android - How to use viewmodel for handling http call in OnCreate which doesn't get called on screen rotation?

Tags: android

. Get stuck with a basic scenario of loading the data in oncreate of an activity. So I am trying to load the data as soon as i open my activity but when i change the screen orientation it gets called again.

below is my rest client for retrofit

```
public class MyRestApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).connectTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/rest/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)

                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

below is my resturl interface for loading the data

```
   public interface MyRestUrlInterface {
    @GET("user/{user_id}")
        Call<Object> getData(@Path("user_id") String user_id);
    }
```

below is my viewmodel class:

```
public class MyViewModelObserver  extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Object> httpCallBackObserver;

    public MutableLiveData<Object> getHttpCallBackObserver() {
        if (httpCallBackObserver == null) {
            httpCallBackObserver = new MutableLiveData<Object>();
        }
        return httpCallBackObserver;
    }
}
```

below is my Activity code :

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private static final String TAG = "MyActivity" ;

 MyRestUrlInterface restUrlInterface;
 public MyViewModelObserver myViewModelObserver;

@Override   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        restUrlInterface = MyRestApiClient.getClient().create(MyRestUrlInterface.class);
        myViewModelObserver = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModelObserver.class);
        myViewModelObserver.getHttpCallBackObserver().observe(this, getData());
        //load data via http
        Call<Object> call = restUrlInterface.getData("123");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
             myViewModelObserver.getHttpCallBackObserver().setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        }


private Observer<Object> getData(){
        return new Observer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final Object responseString) {
                Log.d(TAG,"***** Loaded Data --- "+responseString);

            }
        };
    }
}
```

How to use view model so that it wont make http call again in screen orientation change

suggested answer:

```
public class MyViewModelObserver  extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Object> httpCallBackObserver;

    public MutableLiveData<Object> getHttpCallBackObserver() {
        if (httpCallBackObserver == null) {
            httpCallBackObserver = new MutableLiveData<Object>();
            loadData();

        }
        return httpCallBackObserver;
    }
    private void loadData(){
    Call<Object> call = restUrlInterface.getData("123");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
                 myViewModelObserver.getHttpCallBackObserver().setValue(response.body());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Move all of that Retrofit work *into* the `ViewModel` (or into a repository). The activity should simply be observing the `LiveData` exposed by the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` can then have the smarts to realize "oh, hey, I already have a `LiveData` for this", in case a future activity instance asks for it after a configuration change.

Comment: You mean to say something like suggested answer in question ??

Comment: Yes, though you probably also want to expose the failures through the `LiveData`. Have the `LiveData` expose some `CallResult` object that represents both the success and the failure cases, so the activity can handle both of them.